# Asbestos? What do you think?

Tags: insulation, furnace, asbestos

I originally thought so, but now I'm not so sure.  Thoughts?  It was located around HVAC vents.

[image]

Comment: ... looks like Homasote to me...

Comment: If in doubt, getting it tested isn't very expensive.

Comment: Looks thicker than the material I have tested in the past but similar material. I would have it tested.

Comment: Why are you concerned, do you plan to disturb/remove it?

Comment: How old is the house it is in? If it is built before 1978 (I think?) there is a good possibility.

Comment: I did have it removed by a professional team, but they didn't seem concerned with testing the air afterwards, which made me wonder if it actually was.  The inspector just identified it on sight.